# Перевод текста в PHP

Tags: php, api

Всем привет.
Как мне перевести слово с русского на украинский в PHP? Я получаю стрингу со словом и мне нужно его перевести, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какой то адекватный способ это сделать?
За ранее спасибо!

Comment: Создать словарь, найти в нем это слово, вернуть перевод.

Comment: Воспользоваться АПИ переводчиков от яндекса или гугла
https://github.com/yandex-php/translate-api
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#translate_translate_text-php

Comment: Не, ну это слишком просто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите сделать мультиязычность, то можно так, от браузера подгружается язык

```
preg_match('/^\w{2}/',$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], $matches);
switch (strtolower($matches[0])){
case "ru": $accept_lang="Привет";break;
case "de": $accept_lang="Hallo";break; 
case "en": $accept_lang="Hi";break; 
}
echo $accept_lang;
```